# Attach Multiple Files in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5, email-attachments

I've been trying to attach/upload multiple files in the website I'm making. The Name, Email, Subject & Message are sending but there's no attachment in the message. It seems that the files don't get in the uploads folder. I really don't know what's wrong. Please help me. I'm new with this kind of stuff. Thank you. Here's my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="contact_form block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div id="note"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="fields">

                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromName)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromEmail)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromEmail)
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromSubject)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromSubject, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromSubject)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Multiple", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    <div id="multiple">
                        <input type="file" class="multiple" name="files" multiple />
                    </div>
                    <div id="single">
                        <input type="file" class="single" name="files" /><br />
                        <input type="file" class="single" name="files" /><br />
                        <input type="file" class="single" name="files" /><br />
                    </div>

                }
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-12">                 
                     <div>
                         @if ((TempData["recaptcha"]) != null)
                         {
                            <p>@TempData["recaptcha"]</p>   
                         }
                     </div>
                     <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfVHx8TAAAAAMTDxxQrHDCxO1SyXf1GgbgNBZ5a"></div>
                 </div>

                <div class="col-md-12"><input class="shortcode_button" type="submit" value="Send"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And here's my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmailFormModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string EncodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];
        bool IsCaptchaValid = (ReCaptcha.Validate(EncodedResponse) == "True" ? true : false);
        if(IsCaptchaValid)
        {

            var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("***@gmail.com"));  // replace with valid value 
            message.From = new MailAddress("***@ymailcom");  // replace with valid value
            message.Subject = "Your email subject";
            message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.FromSubject, model.Message);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = "***@gmail.com",  // replace with valid value
                    Password = "***"  // replace with valid value
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                //return RedirectToAction("Sent");
                ViewBag.Message = "Your message has been sent!";

                //TempData["message"] = "Message sent";
                ModelState.Clear();
                return View("Index");
            }

        }else
        {
            TempData["recaptcha"] = "Please verify that you are not a robot!";
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Multiple(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/uploads"), Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)));
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Nested forms are invalid html and not supported (you will not hit the `Multiple()` method). Remove the inner form element and change the `Index()` to include a parameter `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files`, or move the inner form to after the outer form if you want 2 separate methods

Comment: Nested forms are not supported by html. May be this is causing problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help Sir. It's okay now. The files are getting in the "uploads" folder but I still don't receive it in the e-mail. Helps are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your first row of code is the problem.

```
Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"
```

That is a Post action to Index of your home controller. It is not possible to HttpPost another HttpPost, the action itself is expecting an HttpPost, as you can see by the data annotation above the ActionResult name

Why do you use nested forms?

Answer (score 0):

Your view should not be contained nested form submissions. so reduce it to one and the same can be use to upload files.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="contact_form block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div id="note"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fields">

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromName)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromEmail)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromEmail)
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromSubject)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromSubject, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromSubject)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
            {
                <div id="multiple">
                    <input type="file" class="multiple" name="files" multiple />
                </div>
                <div id="single">
                    <input type="file" class="single" name="files" /><br />
                    <input type="file" class="single" name="files" /><br />
                    <input type="file" class="single" name="files" /><br />
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-12">                 
                 <div>
                     @if ((TempData["recaptcha"]) != null)
                     {
                        <p>@TempData["recaptcha"]</p>   
                     }
                 </div>
                 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfVHx8TAAAAAMTDxxQrHDCxO1SyXf1GgbgNBZ5a"></div>
             </div>

            <div class="col-md-12"><input class="shortcode_button" type="submit" value="Send"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Moreever add a parameter to Action to receive files from client request and process it at same action.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmailFormModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //logic here upload file logic here.
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/uploads"), Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)));
            }
        }

        //Rest of business logic here
        string EncodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];
        bool IsCaptchaValid = (ReCaptcha.Validate(EncodedResponse) == "True" ? true : false);
        if(IsCaptchaValid)
        {

            var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("***@gmail.com"));  // replace with valid value 
            message.From = new MailAddress("***@ymailcom");  // replace with valid value
            message.Subject = "Your email subject";
            message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.FromSubject, model.Message);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = "***@gmail.com",  // replace with valid value
                    Password = "***"  // replace with valid value
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                //return RedirectToAction("Sent");
                ViewBag.Message = "Your message has been sent!";

                //TempData["message"] = "Message sent";
                ModelState.Clear();
                return View("Index");
            }

        }else
        {
            TempData["recaptcha"] = "Please verify that you are not a robot!";
        }
    }
    return View(model);

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Sir. The files are getting in the "uploads" folder but I still don't receive it in the e-mail. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @KenHemmo - To attach this file to mail, you can temporary store it to server and attach it to your mail and then dispose it. I hope it will work fine.

Comment: I'll try to do this. And update you if it works. I hope I can still ask you some questions if something when wrong. Thank you so much for your help Sir.